# What is the first value at which a IEEE 64-bit float cannot distinguish two integers?

Tags: integer, double, precision, ieee-754

I am counting on a `Double` (IEEE-conformant 64-bit float) to keep track of some very large numbers. The problem is that I need to maintain unit resolution of integers (the ones place).

The problem is that I know that, as IEEE floats increase in value, they decrease in precision. I am sure that at some point, we get something like this:

```
...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx04
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx05
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx06
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx08
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx10
...
```

where some integers cannot be represented at all. I want to know where that point is, so that I might be able to guard against it, warn users, or set company policy.

---

Note that the I am using floating-point numbers for a good reason; the fraction part is also important to the application, but it is far less important than the integer part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point format uses 53-bit significands. Every finite number it encodes has the form *s* • *F* • 2<sup>*e*</sup>, where *s* (for sign) is +1 or −1, *F* (for fraction) is the number of a 53-bit binary numeral *b*.*bbb*…*bbb* (note the “.” after the first bit), and *e* is an exponent from −1022 to +1023. (Often, floating-point numbers are *normalized* by shifting the bits to move the first 1 bit to the leading *b* position and adjusting the exponent to compensate. For discussion of representable values, we can ignore this; all numbers representable with a leading 0 are also representable with a leading 1, as long as the exponent is within bounds, which it is for this question.)

This tells us everything needed to answer the question. Every integer from 0 to 2<sup>53</sup>−1 is representable in the form +1 • *b*.*bbb*…*bbb* • 2<sup>52</sup> for some combination of values of the bits *b*.*bbb*…*bbb*. And 2<sup>53</sup> is representable as +1 • 1.000…000 • 2<sup>53</sup>. But 2<sup>53</sup>+1 is not representable because it would need an *F* in the form 1.000…0001, where 54 bits are required (the first for 2<sup>53</sup> and the last for 2<sup>0</sup>).

After that, 2<sup>53</sup>+2 is representable, because spanning its highest and lowest 1 bit requires only 53 bits (from 2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>1</sup>). So, at this magnitude, the even integers are representable, and the odd integers are not.

So, the transition from consecutive representable integers to non-representable integers looks like:

- 9,007,199,254,740,919 = 2<sup>53</sup>−3 is representable.
- 9,007,199,254,740,920 = 2<sup>53</sup>−2 is representable.
- 9,007,199,254,740,921 = 2<sup>53</sup>−1 is representable.
- 9,007,199,254,740,922 = 2<sup>53</sup> is representable.
- 9,007,199,254,740,923 = 2<sup>53</sup>+1 is not representable.
- 9,007,199,254,740,924 = 2<sup>53</sup>+2 is representable.
- 9,007,199,254,740,925 = 2<sup>53</sup>+3 is not representable.
- 9,007,199,254,740,926 = 2<sup>53</sup>+4 is representable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers):

> Any integer with absolute value less than 2<sup>24</sup> can be exactly represented in the single precision format, and **any integer with absolute value less than 2<sup>53</sup> can be exactly represented in the double precision format.** Furthermore, a wide range of powers of 2 times such a number can be represented. These properties are sometimes used for purely integer data, to get 53-bit integers on platforms that have double precision floats but only 32-bit integers.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

That is to say, the highest-value integer-precision number for a IEEE 64-bit is **9,007,199,254,740,992**, with the next-highest number being 9,007,199,254,740,994. In your question's format:

```
9007199254740990
9007199254740991
9007199254740992
9007199254740992
9007199254740994
9007199254740996
9007199254740996
```

---

Note that some float-to-string algorithms will print this like:

```
9007199254740990.0
9007199254740991.0
9007199254740992.0
9007199254740992.0
9.007199254740994e+15
9.007199254740996e+15
9.007199254740996e+15
```

Comment: I believe OP’s sample list is a list of representable values, not a list of the results of conversion of successive integers to the format. Given that, your list is not correct; it should be …91, …92, …94, …96,… In any case, I do not know of any software that would print the …93 number for any IEEE-754 64-bit binary value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. I am OP and these were generated by adding `0` through `6` to `9007199254740990` in JavaScript and Swift, respectively.

Comment: I see what you mean about the ...93 number. Thank you for pointing it out; I've corrected it.